# How do i fill in the area between three graphs

Tags: filling

so this is my code
[image]
and this is my output
[image]

My quetion is why does the fill stop at sqrt(3)/2 and does not fill in the rest of the area.
I am trying to make it so that the area between the three graphs is filled in.

Comment: Please include code as text, not pictures.

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[{ArcTan[x], ArcSin[x], Pi/3, If[x < 1, Min[ArcSin[x], Pi/3], Pi/3]}, 
 {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Magenta, Blue, Green, None}, 
 BaseStyle -> Thick, Filling -> {1-> {{4}, {Red, None}}}]
```

[image]